YouTube API on TV Browser loading two players at the same time
So basically, I am using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player, to use the YouTube Player on my NextJS app.
I have two players

First player loads a radio with sound

Second player load a playlist schedule without sound


But there's a problem, because on the computer, the app can load the two players automatically as it should. But on TV Browser, when I try to load the page, the 2º player is paused, and the 1º player plays instead, but when I unpause the 2º player, the 1º player pause automatic.
My guess is that, maybe the YouTube API, don't work too well on TV Browser, or the Smart TV don't have the hardware necessary to load this app
So if anyone maybe know something about it, feel free to help me !
I've tried already doing that the players load after some time, but I didnt get any result at all.
